# Highcharts missing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

After using the second graph on my page which is highstock all my array's disappear.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eu9rV/118/

Tried to place alerts on several parts of the page and after the second graph the array's are a gone.

```
var concatenatedWinddirection = [];
$.each(time, function (i, e) {
    concatenatedWinddirection.push([e, winddirection[i]]);
});


3rd chart: Uncaught ReferenceError: concatenatedWinddirection is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed `$(function(){...` just before `$('#winddirection').highcharts({`.

remove `});` which is just before `$('#winddirection').highcharts({` and put it at the end.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eu9rV/119/)**

Comment: Thanks! but i also got this javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: happy to help you :). For this error, you need to look into check highchart.js and paramter passed to show chart.